# double slash '//' with drupal_goto

Tags: uri

I am using drupal_goto and url methods to try and direct the user to a page.

url returns a string like "/whatever/example" and then I pass that into drupal_goto and they get sent to

localhost//whatever/example

I checked the value for $base_url in settings.php that has no trailing slash. what else could cause this behavior?

Comment: url should be `whatever/example` not `/whatever/example`

Comment: that's what the url() method returns for me when I give it node/<nid>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you pass to `drupal_goto()` will in turn get passed on to the `url()` function. If you're using `url()` on the path before hand, it'll get run through again and you'll get a double slash.

You can just pass the router path to `drupal_goto()` directly, and it will handle the alias for you:

```
drupal_goto('node/1234');
```